# C++ return bool with && in return statement - need clarification

Tags: c++, return, bit-manipulation, ampersand

I'm not entirely sure what happens in this process and what the outcome would be. I've never come across using && in a return or especially a single one in the same return statement.

```
bool myfunction(unsigned int x) 
{
    return x && !(x & (x­ - 1));
}
```

I'd love some clarification as to what happens here and why. I've been looking around but msdn is down and can't seem to find any concrete answers about this type of return.

Comment: This isn't valid C#.

Comment: Does this code compile?  I'm surprised that x is defined as an int but evaluating to a bool...  (that is, the first x, before the &&)

Comment: Is this C/C++? The camelCase method naming and not existing `unsigned` symbol are pretty weird.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Because as others have said, it's not valid C# code and won't even compile.

Comment: `&&` is the logical "AND" operation. Both left and right parts must evaluate to `true` in order for the excision to be `true`

Comment: C++ seems to be the language then.

Comment: @KenRea: of course C# has unsigned ints. `uint` is unsigned. That's what the `u` means.

Comment: Basically, it returns `true` for non-zero even integers. Fix the typo `x1` should be `0x1`.

Comment: There was a slight typo in the return as it was supposed to be x - 1 not x1.  I'm not sure why that happened when I copy pasted it but it did.

Comment: The `&&` operator yields a result of type `int` in C (`0` or `1`) and of type `bool` in C++ (`false` or `true`). It doesn't matter for this example (an `int` result will be implicitly converted to `bool`, with the obvious semantics), but it's still important to remember that C and C++ are *two different languages*. Please decide which one you're using.

Comment: @Ryan that's interesting to know even though the typo was x - 1 not 0x1.

Comment: @KenRea oh, different typo than I thought, so that changes what the function does. `(x & (x-1))` does a bit-wise AND with x and x -1, so you need to look at cases where the bits of both numbers result in 0 (and then negate the 0 to become true). So if x=1 then 1&0=0, but x=3 then 3&2=2. It seems the answer will be true for any non-zero value that is not a power of 2. Think of the binary representation, 0x4 = 0100 and 0x3 = 0011, so 0100&0011 = 0, but 0011&0010=0010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what it means:

- The initial `x` part means `x != 0`
- The `(x & (x-1))` part means "`x` is not a power of two" (i.e. is zero or has more than one bit set)
- The `!(x & (x-­1))` expression means "`x` is a power of two"

Therefore, overall expression means "`x` is a positive power of two".

To see why `x & (x-1)` helps you find powers of two, consider what happens to numbers that have a single bit set vs. the numbers that have two or more bits set. A number with a single bit set, when decremented, would produce a sequence that looks like this:

```
000100000..000 <== x
000011111..111 <== x-1
```

When you apply bitwise-and to a pair of numbers like that, you get zero, because the only bit that has been set in `x` is now zero, and all the bits set in `x-1` were zeros in `x`.

When the number has two or more bits set, the pattern would look like this:

```
010100000..000 <== x
010011111..111 <== x-1
```

Now the last bit that was set would be cleared, but all bits ahead of it would remain set to `1`, producing a non-zero pattern when "AND"-ed with the original value of `x`.

Comment: There was a slight typo in the return as it was supposed to be x - 1 not x1. Does that change this answer?

Comment: The C# tag was removed. It's now tagged both C and C++ (ideally it should be one or the other).

Comment: Thank you. this is very interesting and I've never come across this before. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Had to read the explanation a few times but I feel like I grasp the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The && is the `and` logical operator. It returns true if both left and right expressions are true.
The & is the `and` bitwise operator. Returns the bits that are set on both left and right operands.

Well, this requires further explanation.

Basically, the & operator looks at individual bytes. For instance, consider:

`int x = 1; int y = 2;`

In this case, `x` has 1 bit set (it's, well, 1) and `y` has 1 bit set too (it's 10, 2 in binary).
So, `x & y` would yield `01 & 10` and, consequently, 0, because there are no bits that are set on both `x` and `y`.

In your case, it will return true if `x` is true AND the negation of `x & x1` is something other than 0, because 0 is a falsy value.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx

Comment: There was a slight typo in the return as it was supposed to be x - 1 not x1. Does that change this answer?

Comment: that depends on the value of `x`